# How to remove view that is injected?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, butterknife

I have the following layout, `activity_main.xml`:

```
<merge
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <com.lorentzos.flingswipe.SwipeFlingAdapterView
     android:id="@+id/frame"
     android:background="#d1d1d1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:rotation_degrees="15.5"
     tools:context=".MainActivity"
     android:layout_gravity="top"/>

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tv_noJobsLabel"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:padding="10dp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="18sp"
     android:textColor="#474747"
     android:textAlignment="center"
     tools:text="Nothing Left to Swipe!"
     android:layout_gravity="center" />

  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <include layout="@layout/buttons" />

</merge>
```

In my `main activity`, I have the following code for injection using `ButterKnife`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ButterKnife.inject(this);
```

I want to remove the `<include>` part of the layout because I do not need those buttons anymore, however, when I remove the `<include>` line I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lorentzos.swipecards.example/com.lorentzos.swipecards.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to inject views for com.lorentzos.swipecards.MainActivity@f356341
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there some reason why I cannot remove the `<include>`?

---

**EDIT:**

```
@InjectView(R.id.frame) SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  //Remove title bar
  //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

  //color the notification bar with our company colors
  Window window = this.getWindow();
  window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
  window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
  window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.laborswipe_notificationbar));

  //remove title from action bar and add the logo to the top left of the action bar
  setUpActionBar();

  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  ButterKnife.inject(this);
```

Comment: *ButterKnife.inject(this);* could be this a typo for `ButterKnife.bind(this);` ?

Comment: After removing your `<include layout=.../>`, also remove the binded view from the layout in your activity.

Comment: I think I still need the bind because it binds the frame layout further up in the xml?

Comment: Yes, you still need the bind (`ButterKnife.bind(this)`), but you don't need to bind the view in your `<include layout="@layout/buttons" />` anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. How do I not bind the view? Where else should I remove it from other than the layout file? Removing just the <include> gives the error from the original post.

Comment: binding views with ButterKnife means that you have views in a layout with the binding codes in your `main activity`. So there should be a code with `@BindView(R.id.your_view_in_include_button) View yourViewName;`. Remove this according with the view in your `'include layout`.

Comment: I've modified the original post with the code I have in my main activity for the onCreate and the @InjectView, I don't think that I can remove the entire InjectView because then the frame part is also gone? How can I remove just the layout/buttons section? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I see no error from your code. Try to rebuilding the project.

Comment: You were right,  I did a clean and rebuild and now its fine. If you can put our conversation in an answer I can mark it as the answer

Comment: Have added the answer. Btw, try to update your ButterKnife library to current ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing your `<include layout=.../>` also remove the binded view from the layout in your activity.

Notes:
Binding views with `ButterKnife` means that you have views in a layout with the binding codes in your `main activity`. So there should be a code with:

```
@BindView(R.id.your_view_in_include_button) View yourViewName;
```

Remove this according with the view in your 'include layout. 
Then rebuild your app.

*Suggestion:*
Upgrade your ButterKnife to current version.